# Is a visually impaired person considered a Person with Reduced Mobility (PRM)?

Tags: legal, airlines, accessibility

In Europe, all airlines are required to assist people with reduced mobility. I'm visually impaired, and soon flying with Iberia. So, I called them to ask for assistance at the airport. The guy who answered said that they only offered assistance with wheelchair travel (or something of that sort, the person sproke broken English, and the connection was bad).

I'm going to call again tomorrow during Dutch business hours and ask for help in Dutch (my native language), but in the meantime, if there's any useful info you can give me, that's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be covered.

From [Iberia](https://www.iberia.com/us/fly-with-iberia/special-needs/) web site:

Passengers with Reduced Mobility (PRM) In air transport, current legislation defines a person with a disability or a Passenger with Reduced Mobility (PRM) as "any person whose mobility when using transport is reduced due to any physical disability (**sensory or locomotor, permanent or temporary**), intellectual disability or impairment, or any other cause of disability, or age, and whose situation needs appropriate attention and the adaptation to his or her particular needs of the service made available to all passenger" (art. 2 of EC Regulation 1107/06).

and

"Transfers and **accompaniment in airports**. Transit through airports on occasions requires walking long distances or walking through installations that you are unfamiliar with and which may tire and/or disorient you."

That being said, you need to call the airline to let them know that you will be flying with them and that you are visually impaired, and you will probably be asked to come to the airport earlier, and you will (most) probably be escorted to at least to the departure gate by a airport staff, and there be escorted in the plane by the airline staff.

Comment: Alright. I've tried calling them, but I will call them again. Thank you very much!